# C++ Eigen treat single-element Array as scalar for arithmetc operations

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, eigen

Is there a way of adding two Eigen::ArrayXd arrays both when (a) they have dimension N, or (b) when one of them has dimension N and the other dimension 1?

As an example, I'd the code below to work both when a1 and a2 have the same dimensions, as well as when one of them has dimension 1 (i.e. treat it as a scalar):

```
ArrayXd add_arrays(const ArrayXd& a1, const ArrayXd& a2)
{
   return a1 + a2;
}
```

Of course, this could be solved with an if statement as follows:

```
ArrayXd add_arrays(const ArrayXd& a1, const ArrayXd& a2)
{
   if (a1.size()==1)
      return a1(0) + a2;
   if (a2.size()==1)
      return a1 + a2(0);

   return a1 + a2;
}
```

However, I want to avoid that since the actual code I'm working on would require to repeatedly write a long function specializing all combinations of a1 and a2 having dimensions 1 or N.

Comment: There is no easy workaround for this -- if Eigen wanted to support this, it had to internally do the check you are doing for every `Array+Array` addition at runtime. You should try to clean up your program logic and replace `ArrayXd` by `double` if it actually is a scalar.

Comment: If you're using dynamically sized arrays, there is no way without a runtime check. If all arrays with length 1 are fixed size arrays, it may be doable.